# Sage pay display currency symbol rather than currency initials in totals box

Tags: xslt, opayo

In sage pay, in the totals box, there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way of display the total amount for the order/transaction as £00.00 rather than 00.00GBP.

I can obviously add custom xml into the language file under language = en, however this will then have to be separate for USD being $, not to mention the rest of the worlds currencies cannot depend on thier language.

So basically is it possible to display the symbol in this area?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

amended countries.xml
from:

```
    <country>
        <code>GB</code>
        <name>United Kingdom</name>
    </country>
```

to:

```
    <country>
        <code>GB</code>
        <name>United Kingdom</name>
        <currencysymbol>£</currencysymbol>
    </country>
```

Then at the top of the relevant template .xslt file added:

```
<xsl:variable name="countriesFile" select="document('countries.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="countryCode" select="payment-model/vendor/countrycode" />
```

Then to retrieve the relevant symbol:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$countriesFile/countries/country[code=$countryCode]/currencysymbol"/>
```